# GitHub Action - trigger on push from branch A to branch B, but not fork to branch B

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions

My Repo has Branches `Apple`, `Banana` & `master`.

I want to run the action when I push from Branch `Apple` to Branch `Banana`, but NOT when Pull Requests are merged into `Branch B`.

Current Draft of the action starts as;

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - Banana
```

But, if I merge a PR from a fork into branch `Banana`, the action will still trigger - How can I stop this?

I've seen the Workflow Syntax about using an IF statement [(HERE)](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif), but that has no option for "from branch `Apple`"

Comment: What about `if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'`?

Comment: @dan1st that would make the workflow only work if pushed to `main`. I already have it to only work when Apple is pushed to Banana, but PRs to Banana will also trigger the action

Comment: You may be able to use the [`GITHUB_EVENT_NAME` or `GITHUB_BASE_REF` environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) to check for pull reqests.